# Permissions corrupted in OS X

Tags: command-line, macos, filesystem

I have run `sudo chown -R Ankur /` by mistake and now some apps are not opening and there icons are also not visible. How can I fix this?

Here are some snapshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ouch - when is the last backup? How much time would you take to boot to recovery and reinstall OS X which would undo the damage made to the system parts...? That decides if you just reinstall or want to slowly patch together the unix commands so that you can try to make a backup or undo the damage.

Comment: @bmike  there is no way to correct this problem? Actually some apps are working. i tried to fix the permissions by repairing permissions from Onyx app but still not working.

Comment: Sure you can correct the problem. There are probably 200k files on the machine that you changed permissions on. You could research what each was supposed to be and fix them by hand or by script. That's not an efficient manner to proceed, though unless you wanted the challenge to try.

Comment: @bmike actually when i ran this command osx showed "Operation not permitted" and after 30-40secs i cancelled the operation. show i don't think there is other problems.Just apps are not working.

Comment: I'll answer how to get pas the Application failing - both short term and long term then.

Comment: From the looks of it, you did not only run `chown` but also `chmod`, correct?

Comment: No just `chown`

Comment: This doesn't explain permissions for "Android Studio.app" and others. The problem they can't be executed is not file/directory ownership but inaccessibility of the application itself. Try `sudo chmod -R a+x Android\ Studio.app` and then double-click it again.

Answer (score 1):

Short term, you can turn off Gatekeeper to allow the application you corrupted to run.

- Open system preferences
- Select Security & Privacy
- Select general
- Select **Anywhere**

The system should have protected most of the command line tools, but I would see if you can make one last back up of the system and then restore the OS if applications installed by the system are messed up.

Specifically, my Macbook has 60 million files - so had I run that command, I would have a lot of work to do to ensure everything is correct and staring with deleting all apps I can easily reinstall and then reinstalling the system if I broke any system apps is far shorter a path to recovery.

Luckily - all your personal files were already owned by your user, so this exercise in recovery will be to get copied of apps that are not unique to your system and at worst, you'll need to delete preference and configuration files and re-create them if they need permissions different than what you enforced on your system.

Comment: Yes its huge task and i don't want to spend my night formatting everything.Also the problem is i deleted app (google chrome) and again installed . Now app is running but icon is not available.

Comment: I would let Time Machine run overnight and then try restarting when you have time to reinstall the OS if needed. Depending on what parts of the drive the command reached before you killed it, you still have other damage elsewhere from which to recover.

Comment: Yes i would be thankful you can tell me how to fix only applications for time being.

Comment: See my edit if you don't know what "gatekeeper" is and how to disable it. Once that's done, you might ask a follow on question for one specific app. It's hard to guess how all apps are broken or if they are really broken other than not being correctly signed anymore.